# Shift values in numpy array by differing amounts

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `a = np.array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 15, 7, 7, 9])` that continues like that. I would like to shift this array but I'm not sure if I can use `np.roll()` here.

The array I would like to produce is `[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 15, 15, 7]`.

As you can see, the first like numbers which are in array `a` (in this case the three '2's) should be replaced with '0's. Everything should then be shifted such that the '3's are replaced with '2's, the '15' is replaced with the '3' etc. Ideally I would like to do this operation without any for loop as I need it to run quickly.

I realise this operation may be a bit confusing so please ask questions.

Comment: Kudos for the nicely asked, interesting NumPy challenge. If only `np.unique()` had an unsorted option, this would be a one-liner.

Comment: Do you have recurring values in `a`?

Comment: Yep, I do @Ivan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with NumPy, you can achieve this using [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) by returning the counts per unique elements with the `return_counts` option.

Then, simply roll the values and construct a new array with [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> s, i, c = np.unique(a, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
(array([ 2,  3,  7,  9, 15]), array([0, 3, 6, 8, 5]), array([3, 2, 2, 1, 1]))
```

The three outputs are respectively: *unique sorted elements*, *indices of first encounter unique element*, and *the count per unique element*.

`np.unique` sorts the value, so **we need to unsort the values as well as the counts** first. We can then shift the values with [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
>>> idx = np.argsort(i)
>>> v = np.roll(s[idx], 1)
>>> v[0] = 0
array([ 0,  2,  3, 15,  7])
```

Alternatively with [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), this requires a whole copy though:

```
>>> v = np.append([0], s[idx][:-1])
array([ 0,  2,  3, 15,  7])
```

Finally reassemble:

```
>>> np.repeat(v, c[idx])
array([ 0,  0,  0,  2,  2,  3, 15, 15,  7])
```

---

Another - *more general* - solution that will work when there are recurring values in `a`. This requires the use of [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html).

You can get the indices of the elements with:

```
>>> i = np.diff(np.append(a, [0])).nonzero()[0] + 1
array([3, 5, 6, 8, 9])

>>> idx = np.append([0], i)
array([0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

The values are then given using `a[idx]`:

```
>>> v = np.append([0], a)[idx]
array([ 0,  2,  3, 15,  7,  9])
```

And the counts per element with:

```
>>> c = np.append(np.diff(i, prepend=0), [0])
array([3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0])
```

Finally, reassemble:

```
>>> np.repeat(v, c)
array([ 0,  0,  0,  2,  2,  3, 15, 15,  7])
```

Comment: Clever — I got frustrated with trying to unsort the uniques.

Comment: The resulting array seems to be incorrect though. It should be `[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 15, 15, 7]`. Also, what if some value of the array changes and then shows up again e.g. `[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2]`?

Comment: Indeed this won't work with recurring values in `a`. I have fixed the error, the array of counts `c` also needs to be unsorted...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and well-explained solution!

Comment: @bb1, and OP - I have an alternative solution which will work with recurring values in `a`.

Comment: For line `c = np.append(np.diff(x, prepend=0, append=x[-1] + 1), [0])` I am getting error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My bad, it should be `c = np.append(np.diff(i, prepend=0, append=i[-1] + 1), [0])` with variable `i`, not `x`.

Comment: The solution does not seem to work for `a = cp.array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 15, 7, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7])`, with the resulting array coming out as `[ 0  0  0  2  2  3 15 15  7  9  9  7  8]` rather than `[ 0  0  0  2  2  3 15 15  7  9  9  7  8 8 8]`

Comment: Fixed it with c[-2] = int(len(a) - (c.sum()-1))

Comment: Glad you found a way around it, I was actually editing my answer, see above...

Answer (score 2):

This is not using numpy, but one approach that comes to mind is to `itertools.groupby` to collect contiguous runs of the same elements. Then shift all the elements (by prepending a `0`) and use the counts to repeat them.

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

def shift(data):
    values = [(k, len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(data)]
    keys = [0] + [i[0] for i in values]
    reps = [i[1] for i in values]
    return list(chain.from_iterable([[k]*rep for k, rep in zip(keys, reps)]))
```

For example

```
>>> a = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,15,7,7,9])
>>> shift(a)
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 15, 15, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 15, 7, 7, 9])
diff_a=np.diff(a)
idx=np.flatnonzero(diff_a)
val=diff_a[idx]
val=np.insert(val[:-1],0, a[0]) #update value
diff_a[idx]=val
res=np.append([0],np.cumsum(diff_a))
print(res)
```

Comment: Although this was the fastest solution, it does not work when elements are repeated. For example, it does not work for array `a = np.array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 15, 7, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 7])`

Comment: a is        [ 2  2  2  3  3 15  7  7  9  7  7  8  7]
result is [ 0  0  0  2  2  3 15 15  7  9  9  7  8] Where is my mistake?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, it seems when I updated your code to work in cupy it did not work for more complex examples like the one I gave above. Apparently cupy does not have `cp.insert()` so I had to find a work around for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 15, 7, 7, 9])

z = a - np.pad(a, (1,0))[:-1]
z[m] = np.pad(z[(m := z!=0)], (1,0))[:-1]
print(z.cumsum())
```

It gives:

```
[ 0  0  0  2  2  3 15 15  7]
```

Comment: `print(z)` did not give `array([ 0,  0,  0,  2,  2,  3, 15, 15,  7])`

Comment: The result is `z.cumsum()`, so try `print(z.cumsum())` instead.